# Changing an exe to show a different process name in task manager

Tags: java, cmd, vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

How do you change a name of a process of an executable to show a different name in the task manager?

I am trying to rename the processes of `Real VNC`.

I have tried to just rename the executable vncserver.exe and vncserverui.exe to something different but then the executable would not open.

Does any one have any ideas or examples that would help put me on the correct path?

I would think just changing the name of the executable and having the target hit that new name would work fine. But for some reason it does not.

Any advice?

(I have been tasked with this challenge but I cannot find any information on this anywhere. I have tried changing all the executable names to match properly and nothing worked.)

Also tried creating a cmd file to start like this:

`start "Title" /HIGH ""C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Server\vncguihelper.exe" vncserver.exe -_fromGui -start -showstatus"`

Comment: Renaming a VNC process like that at runtime sounds extremely dodgy

Comment: Looking at some example apps using a hex editor, the strings I see named in the TaskMgr, didn't show up in the binary itself.  You might look in the abyss of the Windows Registry to see if the string is written their by some process.   Good luck.